# Where can get different satellite images for the same scene?

Tags: data, imagery, satellite

In a research paper, the authors make an experiment using 4 different images which are SPOT band 4, PalSAR HH polarization, Landsat TM band 5, DEM data. I attach one figure as example http://prntscr.com/fv6j9t.

I want to get images from a different source for the same scene. where can I find this for free?

Comment: One source: http://apps.sentinel-hub.com/eo-browser

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are various sources, all of which can be found by searching the internet.

Comment: I do alot of search but it's not easy to find good satellite images for same place

Answer (score 2):

Give the USGS a shot. You select location and types of data, then pick the available source

[USGS Earth Explorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/)

Comment: I was trying this before but each place have only one kind of images or very very old

Answer (score 2):

The types of imagery you've listed are from a number of different sources, and it might be difficult to find all of them from one place or for free (but there might be a repository that makes this easier for you. I know of a few for imagery of the polar regions - Polar Geospatial Center and Alaska Satellite Facility).

As @jpmaniac87 said, [USGS](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) will provide pretty easy access to the Landsat suite of sensors as well as MODIS, which should have a [coarse resolution] DEM for free. Imagery from other US owned satellites should also be freely available, but repositories vary. I can't provide any input on PalSAR, and I personally have had issues getting imagery from SPOT (I believe imagery five years and older should be free to the international community). The [European Space Agency (ESA)](https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/eoli) also has some freely available imagery, which I believe includes radar datasets. There are many other observational satellite datasets out there, but these are just some of the ones I know best.

Your question is challenging to answer specifically without additional defining characteristics besides "for free". What type of imagery are you looking for (radar?, optical?, one of each? images from the four specific sources you mention?) and what type of spatial resolution do you need? Also, does it matter when the scene is from?

Comment: I don't mention the image type because it's not matter for me since it carry same features. Also, I didn't look for specific location .. any same scene from any place will work fine for me. Regarding to resolution I can do resampling for them.

Answer (score 1):

- [National Weather Service](https://www.weather.gov/gis/)
- [NOAA](https://gis.ncdc.noaa.gov/maps/ncei).  Actually, NOAA has a *lot*.  This link is just to one
  part of the GIS data they provide.
- If its data from inside the US, most states have a GIS office.  Check
  the state datasets.  [Here's a list](https://library.uoregon.edu/map/map_section/map_Statedatasets.html) of links to state-by-state
  data from University of Oregon.
- [US Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/)
- [MIT](http://libguides.mit.edu/gis/states)

Where do you need the data for?  USA-centric responses don't do you much good if you need information on someplace like [Australia](http://www.ga.gov.au/data-pubs) or [Cyprus](http://www.geoportal.gov.cy/MOI/DLS/geoportal/geoportal.nsf/index_en/index_en?OpenDocument).